# How to disable 'no-unused-vars' rule in nuxt project

Tags: nuxt.js, eslint

Here's my .eslintrc.js file in my nuxt project:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint'
  },
  extends: [
    '@nuxtjs',
    'prettier',
    'prettier/vue',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
    'plugin:nuxt/recommended'
  ],
plugins: ['prettier'],
// add your custom rules here
  rules: {
    'nuxt/no-cjs-in-config': 'off',
    'no-unused-vars': 'off'
  }
}
```

After I added `'no-unused-vars': 'off'` the red line under the undefined variables in VSCode were gone, but when I run the dev server console still shows `xxx is not defined` and block my website. I've tried `/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */` in my component but it doesn't work. The only way worked was to add `/* eslint-disable */` but it would disable all rules since I don't want this to happen. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

it should be

```
rules: {
    ...
    'vue/no-unused-vars': 'off'
  }
```

Side note: If you want to disable eslint entirely then rather than going to `.eslintrc` and adding rules you can disable the entire eslint by just commenting the same in nuxt.config.js file. I do this when I am developing. :D

```
buildModules: [
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/eslint-module
    //'@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
  ],
```

Comment: I tried 'vue/no-unused-vars': 'off' but it still doesn't work. If I can not find a way I may consider disable the whole eslint by commenting '@nuxtjs/eslint-module' as you do. Anyway thanks for your help

Comment: Once you add the rule to .eslintrc then you need to restart the project to get this change effective.

Answer (score 1):

This also helps to Hide error on page, but, It will show on Console.

`nuxt.config.js`

```
  build: {
    hotMiddleware: {
      client: {
        // turn off client overlay when errors are present
        overlay: false
      }
    }
  }
```